# How can i optimize my sql query to execute in a shorter time

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, subquery

I have the following `ActiveRecord` query

```
LoanApplication.joins(:case_status => :loan_case).where.not(case_code: nil).group("loan_cases.id, loan_cases.case_status").select("loan_cases.case_status, count(loan_applications.id)").order("loan_cases.rank ASC")
```

which when broken down with a `.explain` gives the following query plan

```html
QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=2924.84..2924.85 rows=1 width=532)
   Sort Key: loan_cases.rank
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..2924.83 rows=1 width=532)
         Group Key: loan_cases.id
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..2918.67 rows=1230 width=528)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..1898.81 rows=1765 width=528)
                     Join Filter: (case_statuses.loan_case_id = loan_cases.id)
                     ->  Index Scan using loan_cases_pkey on loan_cases  (cost=0.14..12.45 rows=1 width=524)
                           Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
                     ->  Seq Scan on case_statuses  (cost=0.00..1423.03 rows=37066 width=8)
                           Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
               ->  Index Scan using loan_applications_pkey on loan_applications  (cost=0.29..0.58 rows=1 width=4)
                     Index Cond: (id = case_statuses.loan_application_id)
                     Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (case_code IS NOT NULL))
(14 rows)
```

or the following SQL query

```
 SELECT loan_cases.case_status, count(loan_applications.id) FROM
 "loan_applications" INNER JOIN "case_statuses" ON
 "case_statuses"."loan_application_id" = "loan_applications"."id" AND
 "case_statuses"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "loan_cases" ON
 "loan_cases"."id" = "case_statuses"."loan_case_id" AND
 "loan_cases"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE
 "loan_applications"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
 ("loan_applications"."case_code" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY loan_cases.id,
 loan_cases.case_status  ORDER BY loan_cases.rank ASC"
```

create table definitions

```
create_table "loan_applications", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "email"
  t.string "case_code"
end

create_table "loan_cases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "case_status", limit: 255
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "can_flow_to"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.integer  "rank"
  end

create_table "case_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "loan_application_id"
  t.integer "loan_case_id"
end
add_index "case_statuses", ["loan_application_id"], name: "index_case_statuses_on_loan_application_id", using: :btree
```

Rails Model

```
class LoanApplication 
  has_one :case_status, inverse_of: :loan_application, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :loan_case, :through => :case_status, :source => :loan_case
end

class CaseStatus
  belongs_to :loan_application, inverse_of: :case_status
  belongs_to :loan_case
end

class LoanCase
  has_many :case_statuses
end
```

This executes in about 239ms but I believe it can be shorter and asking if there is any way this can be optimized better?

Comment: You tagged both MySQL and PostgreSQL. Which is it? The best answer depends on which RDBMS you use. Using tags accurately helps to attract the attention of the people best able to answer your question.

Comment: Also, thank you for providing the EXPLAIN report, but you should know that any query optimization question should also include the `CREATE TABLE` definition of your table. And please don't post a screenshot, post text. If people want to test your table and query, it's helpful to provide the **text** definition of the table, so they can copy & paste.

Comment: @BillKarwin its postgresql

Comment: Please could you let us know the indexes present on the tables, and whether you're able to add any new indexes?

Comment: Could you post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, as text and not as image?

Comment: @MatBailie only an index on case_status table for loan_application_id and yes can add new indexes